# Angular 6 mat-table using sticky column with flex does not work

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material, sticky

I am using angular 7, Material 7

I am trying to use sticky for specific column and it does not work,

the header getting sticky but the cell don't.

My html look as below:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceVaccinations" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Gender" sticky>
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let GetSummaryRecordsVaccinations">
          <img [attr.src]="getGenderIcon(Gender)" />
        </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="IdentityNumber" sticky>
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> מס' זהות </mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let GetSummaryRecordsVaccinations" > {{IdentityNumber}} </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="CodeVaccinationsAllowed">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ניתן לחסן סיכום </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let GetSummaryRecordsVaccinations">
                <img [attr.src]="getIcon(CodeVaccinationsAllowed)"/> </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="שפעת">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> שפעת </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let GetSummaryRecordsVaccinations">
                <div class="center">{{ClassDescription}}
                  <br/>{{VaccinationDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                </div>
              </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row class="mat-row-header-vaccination" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedVaccinationsAllColumns; sticky:true"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row class="mat-row-vaccination" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedVaccinationsAllColumns;" (click)="selection.select(row)"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

the `mat-row-header` is declared with `min-width` in order to add horizontal scroll

Each of my column has specific width using the code like following

```
flex: 0 0 50px;
```

any idea to resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the problem.

the material design changed in version `7.1.1`.

In order to use sticky column you need to use `<table mat-table></table>` tag instead of `<mat-table></mat-table>` and `<th mat-header-cell>`,`<td mat-cell>` instead of `<mat-header-cell>` and `<mat-cell>`

This is how my table now look like:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceVaccinations" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Gender" sticky>
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let GetSummaryRecordsVaccinations">
          <img [attr.src]="getGenderIcon(Gender)" />
        </td>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="IdentityNumber" sticky>
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> מס' זהות </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let GetSummaryRecordsVaccinations" > {{IdentityNumber}} </td>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="CodeVaccinationsAllowed">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ניתן לחסן סיכום </th>
              <td *matCellDef="let GetSummaryRecordsVaccinations">
                <img [attr.src]="getIcon(CodeVaccinationsAllowed)"/> </td>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container matColumnDef="שפעת">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> שפעת </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let GetSummaryRecordsVaccinations">
                <div class="center">{{ClassDescription}}
                  <br/>{{VaccinationDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                </div>
              </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row class="mat-row-header-vaccination" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedVaccinationsAllColumns; sticky:true"></tr>
            <tr mat-row class="mat-row-vaccination" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedVaccinationsAllColumns;" (click)="selection.select(row)"></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: hy there, i want to ask what happen to your sticky column when there is 2 column that need to be sticky? did the table become mess up?

Comment: no, I did it and it work perfectly, which browser and what version are u use?

Comment: hy there i guess there is something with the width of the column

Answer (score 1):

the angular material doesnot work if we do some changeing in the table width so basicly i put this css to make all the columns have same width

```
.mat-header-cell, .mat-footer-cell, .mat-cell {
  min-width: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;

}
```

and now it works thaks