# Angular table with sticky columns working with Chrome and failing with Firefox

Tags: html, css, angular

Angular sticky columns aren't working on Firefox browser, Even the examples in the documentation aren't working.

Table with sticky columns example:

https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702517/angular-6-mat-table-using-sticky-column-with-flex-does-not-work maybe containing the answer to your question? Haven't checked the answers, but it seems it's the same problem

Comment: Thank you but this is a different issue. I already use mat-header-cell and it works fine in chrome and isn't working in Firefox.